# Is 30MB/s Normal For a 7200RPM 320GB HDD

Tags: hard-drive, performance, sata, speed

I recently started noticing some texture loading issues in a couple of games. I had noticed these problems long ago and have now realized that from that time I have replaced every component in my PC other than the HDD and I am starting to think that this is the culprit.

My hard drive came from a Dell Latitude laptop, it is a [Seagate Momentus Thin SATA ST320LT007 320GB](https://www.seagate.com/staticfiles/support/disc/manuals/notebook/momentus/Thin%20(.2)/100625253c.pdf).

Anyways I did some file copying tests and found that when copying a 3GB rar file from my desktop to my documents folder it started with around 40-50Mb/s but then dropped down to around 30MB/s for the rest of the transfer. Is this a normal speed you could expect from a HDD?

I also ran CrystalDiskMark and here is the screenshot of the results:

[image]

Comment: Performance degrades over time. Yours is probably very old.

Comment: So is the performance that mine was showing very bad?

Comment: They aren't good for sure, especially with small files. I've seen the same "mistake" too many times: User replace parts willy nilly just to find out the actual bottleneck is the HDD.

Comment: At least I didn't pay for most of the parts or had a different reason to change them, my PCIE port on my mobo fried both the mobo itself and the GPU. Then I got a new mobo + free cpu combo and bought a new gpu aswell. Then I upgraded my ram from 4 to 6GB aswell.  I thought the problems were with my windows install...

Comment: The inadequacy of the hardware does not preclude other software issues.

Comment: Before investing in new hardware, clean up the HDD and defragment. How much free space is left?

Comment: I note also that your S.M.A.R.T. data shows disk errors. Might be time for a change.

Comment: I have a around 80GB free, I defragged it around a week ago and it is 0% fragmented.

Comment: I did some research, the HDD is around 4-5 years old.

Comment: I just measured 30MB/s on a similar drive, although mine is a 5400rpm model. This was on a file copy; a read test (copy to null device) measured 80MB/s. Note that defragmenting will optimise a read test, but most defragmenters do not optimise free space, so a copy operation is likely to produce a fragmented target, with consequent overhead. It is very common for copy speeds to drop during the operation, as the initial reads are likely to come from cache. I don't think your measurement for a copy operation is particularly poor, but you should note the other comments, especially @harrymc's.

Comment: @Mihkel And the drive model dates back from 2010 or 2011. Your purchase and using the drive might only be 4-5 years old, but it could be older. Regardless that drive is dying and the only solution is to get a new drive.

Comment: @JakeGould yep, I'm looking at some WD Blue drives at my local stores right now. Might even get an SSD for windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your disk is showing [S.M.A.R.T.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.) errors.
If we combine this with degraded performance, the prognostic is not good.

I suggest to backup quickly your data, before the disk fails, then replace it.
The saved data should be verified, as much as you can, since you did have
unrecoverable errors on the disk.